# Github отсоединение от разветвлённого проекта

Tags: git, github, repository

Это мой github
[image: projects]

Когда я только зарегистрировался в гитхаб то присоединился и разветвил (или как это называется) вот этот репозиторий.

Вопрос: как убрать этот репозиторий с моей страницы, как отсоединиться от него.

[image: to stop forked]

я пробовал Github Watch но там его нет
[image: github watch]

Comment: я тогда даже непонял что я сделал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форк - это фактически полноценная копия чужого репозитория, и каждый форк - это уже ваш репозиторий (репозиторий на вашем аккаунте). Если форк создан ошибочно, то его нужно не "отсоединить", а просто удалить.

Удаление форка выполняется точно так же, как и любого своего репозитория: заходите в репозиторий (в свой форк, не в исходный репозиторий, от которого сделан форк), там переходите в Settings, прокручиваете до самого низа, в красной "Danger zone" нажимаете красную кнопку "Delete this repository", подтверждаете удаление (для этого нужно будет ввести имя_аккаунта/имя_репозитория, так как будет указано, у вас будет скорее всего `andriy-byte/SwanSword`).